# NPOI - Loading an Excel file causes Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, npoi

Has anybody an idea what may cause this error

> 'Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0'

```
var path = @"C:\Excel.xls";

using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}
```

Im using: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Leaving this in case other people pass by here.

`.xls` is the old Excel format. With that format you should create a new `HSSFWorkbook` instance. The `XSSFWorkbook` is used with the new `.xlsx` format.

Both types implement the `IWorkbook` interface so you can build your code around this interface and determine the workbook instance's type at runtime.

I created a simple Excel component and here is the constructor:

```cs
private readonly bool _useOldExcelFormat;
private readonly IWorkbook _workbook;

public NpoiExcelManager(bool useOldExcelFormat = false)
{
    _useOldExcelFormat= useOldExcelFormat;
    if (_useOldExcelFormat)
    {
        _workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }
    else
    {
        _workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }
}
```

You'll discover a few differences between `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook` so sometimes you'd have to write specific code for each implementation but those cases are very rare.

I'd say around 95% of the `IWorkbook` interface is working for both implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution:

Saved that Excel file as an `.xlsx` but without macros or `.xlsm` and it worked